# VPN into SonicWall behind another NAT/Router

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

The SonciWall has been put behind another device and despite everything being forwarded to the SonicWall I can no longer VPN in (**UPDATE:** "The peer is not responding to phase 1 ISAKMP requests" is logged in the global VPN client).

I think this is something to do with the IKE exchange using ISKAMP (although the 2 UDP ports Group policy sets in the firewall are also forwarded) being dropped by the new device.

Is there anything I can do? Is it possible to use a different method than IKE to establish VPN?

FYI:

- It is a SonicWall TZ170
- Internet connection is up
- I have the correct IP - I can connect using other applications

Comment: What do you mean by you can not VPN in? Connection refused? Connection time out? Try to be as clear as possible. Please.

Comment: cannot establish a vpn connection - see update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change the modem/router for one with that could be set to bridging pass though mode - PPPoE then has to be setup on the SonicWall.

Turns out some modem/routers just wont cut it.

SonicWall have a dedicated article to the issue: http://www.sonicwall.com/downloads/GVC_Peer_is_Not_Responding_to_Phase_1_Requests.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you forwarded UDP ports - what about the different IP protocols? (AH and ESP - IP protocol numbers 50 and 51 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers). Do you have those two forwarded to the SonicWall?

Comment: I would if I could - but it seems to only forward UDP and TCP :(

Comment: What device is in front of the Sonicwall?